# How can I get the font cursor at top, text-align: top?

Tags: html, css, fonts, textarea, height

If i set the css for textarea like this=>

```
#id_content {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

The height and width work.
But if i type something on textarea texts are at the middle of the height of the textarea though the padding:0.

Why is it happenning? How can i fix it?

This is the html source=>

```
<div id="id_div_content">

<form action="/createpost/" method="post"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='xxx' value='xxx' /></div>
<p><label for="id_title">Title:</label> <input id="id_title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" /></p>

    <p><label for="id_content">Content:</label> <input type="text" name="content" id="id_content" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YEsKq/ Looks fine to me? The text is on the top.

Comment: You must have another rule that overwrites the default text-align?

Comment: This is the full css, check this to understand more. http://pastebin.com/QezMc9iu   , http://pastebin.com/bjeLbqFw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens if you are using the input tag in your html as such:

```
<input type="textarea" id="id_content" />
```

If you are, use the textarea tag instead:

```
<textarea id="id_content"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Not <textarea> rather `<input type="text" name="content" id="id_content" />`

Comment: If you want a 600px textbox, you should use `<textarea>`.

Comment: @guru Try changing it to `<textarea id="id_content" name="content"> </textarea>`. I'm pretty sure it will work now.